# Connecting JSON object data with individual divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

So I'm trying to build a site that lists a variety of fruits and indicates if they are currently in season. I've built a JSON object that has the name of the fruit, an array that shows the months that the fruit is in season and a `boolean` set to `false`.

My `html` for each fruit follows this pattern:

```
 <div id="mulberries" class="fruit mulberries">
            <span class="fruitText">Mulberries</span>
            <div class="fruitPic mulberriesPic">
                <div class="layer">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

There's a div for each fruit in my `JSON` data

My `JSON` data looks like this:

```
var fruits = [

        {
            "name":"mulberries",
            "ripeMonths": ["07", "08"],
            "isRipe": false, 
        },
        {
            "name":"nectarines",
            "ripeMonths": ["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"],
            "isRipe": false,
        },
        {
            "name":"oranges",
            "ripeMonths": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"],
            "isRipe": false,
        },
```

I'm getting the data from the current month like so:

```
 var month = new Date();
 var mm = month.getMonth()+1;

 if(mm<10) {
 mm='0'+mm
 }

 month = mm;
```

And them I'm leveraging that data against the `JSON` object to change the `boolean` value to `true` if the `month` is equal to any value within the `ripeMonths` array using this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
if (fruits[i].ripeMonths.indexOf(month) > -1) {

    (fruits[i].isRipe) = true
} else {
    (fruits[i].isRipe) = false
}

};
```

So, what I want to be able to do is use `CSS` on the `div class= "layer"`, to highlight the fruits that are currently in season and eventually have all of the divs indicate what the actual ripe months are on a hover event. What I can't seem to figure out is how to connect that `JSON` data itself to its respective `div`.

What I've read so far points me towards us jQuery's `.data(key, value)`, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to load the data via AJAX?

Comment: What is `mulberries` doing in `<div id="mulberries" class="fruit" "mulberries">`? Was that supposed to be part of the class?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I don't think so, ut I'll look into AJAX to see if that helps me here.

Comment: @Barmar It should be `<div id="mulberries" class="fruit mulberries">` I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create them dynamically you can try to use this kind of format. I am only showing a few nested objects, but you it's the same thing.

Using jQuery is very similar.. instead of using append, you can do .innerHTML when you have a parent object.

```js
var fruits = [

    {
        "name": "mulberries",
        "ripeMonths": ["07", "08"],
        "isRipe": false,
    },
    {
        "name": "nectarines",
        "ripeMonths": ["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"],
        "isRipe": false,
    },
    {
        "name": "oranges",
        "ripeMonths": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"],
        "isRipe": false,
    }
];


var month = new Date();
var mm = month.getMonth() + 1;

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

month = mm;

for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if (fruits[i].ripeMonths.indexOf(month) > -1) {

        (fruits[i].isRipe) = true
    } else {
        (fruits[i].isRipe) = false
    }
};

function render() {
    for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        var fruit = document.createElement('div');
        fruit.setAttribute('id', fruits[i].name);
        fruit.setAttribute('class', 'fruit');

        var fruitText = document.createElement('span');
        fruitText.setAttribute('class', 'fruitText');

        var fruitTextNode = document.createTextNode(fruits[i].name);
        fruitText.appendChild(fruitTextNode);

        fruit.appendChild(fruitText);
        document.body.appendChild(fruit);
    }
}

render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop can find the `layers` DIV that's inside the corresponding fruit DIV, and add or remove a class that affects the CSS.

```
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if (fruits[i].ripeMonths.indexOf(month) > -1) {
        (fruits[i].isRipe) = true;
        document.querySelector(".fruit." + fruits[i].name + " .layer").classList.add("inseason");
    } else {
        (fruits[i].isRipe) = false;
        document.querySelector(".fruit." + fruits[i].name + " .layer").classList.remove("inseason");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to:

1. Set the fruit's name.
2. Set their ripe months and show then in a hover.
3. Highlight only the fruits that are actually ripping.

Unless you need all that HTML 'cause of other force reasons (i.e. they are a component), I think you can do that only with that `<span>` (or a `<p>`, whatever).

Your doubts about `data(key, value)` are just exaggerated: maybe if you read instead `prop(key, value)` you'll understand better...

The only difference between those two methods is that `data` sets a [`data-*`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) HTML attribute (you could do the same work with normal attrs like `id`, but I think it's nice to separate that type of data). And for this case, you don't even need it; with [`title`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) you can achieve that hovering effect.

Now that you know what to do, we can get to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
     * Your fruits here. If you can change the ripe months and set it to
     * numbers, would make code shorter and faster. If not, just set the var
     * "month" as you are doing actually with the zero AND as a string
     * (".toString()").
     */
    var fruits = [
        {"name": "Apple", "ripeMonths": [3]},
        {"name": "Banana", "ripeMonths": [8]}
    ];
    var container = $("#fruits");
    var month = (new Date().getMonth() + 1);


    $.each(fruits, function(i, fruit) {
        /*
         * We'll create a span for each fruit, set the hover text for the
         * ripe info and the highligth class.
         */
        var p = $("<p>");
        var title = "The fruit is riped on ".concat(
            fruit.ripeMonths.join(", ")
        );

 
        // You can concatenate then all in the same line.
        p.text(fruit.name);
        // Now the paragraph will show the fruit's ripe months on hover.
        p.prop("title", title);
        // Only if is a ripping month.
        if (fruit.ripeMonths.indexOf(month) != -1) {
            p.addClass("highligth");
        }

        // We append the new fruit to the fruits container.
        container.append(p);
    });
});
```

```css
.highligth:hover {
    /* Visual */
    background-color: khaki;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- You can do all of it without jQuery, only pointing it if you don't need it for anything else and want to simplify vendors -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional, just because I like it -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fruits status</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Just to store in a nicely place separated from all other things. -->
    <div id="fruits"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need to maintain your actual HTML structure, just create all the elements as I did with the `<p>`, set the `title` to the main `<div>`, the text to the inner `<span>`, and add the class `highligth` to `<div class="layer">`.